# Based on a condition, convert a week date to day on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset, which have year, month, week and sales numbers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['year'] = [2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012]
df['month'] = [12,12,12,1,1,1]
df['week'] = [51,52,53,1,2,3]
df['sales'] = [10000,12000,11000,5000,12000,11000]
df['date_ix'] = df['year'] * 1000 + (df['week']-1) * 10 + 1
df['date_week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_ix'], format='%Y%W%w')
df

    year    month   week    sales   date_ix date_week
0   2011    12      51      10000   2011501 2011-12-12
1   2011    12      52      12000   2011511 2011-12-19
2   2011    12      53      11000   2011521 2011-12-26
3   2012    1       1       5000    2012001 2011-12-26
4   2012    1       2       12000   2012011 2012-01-02
5   2012    1       3       11000   2012021 2012-01-09
```

Now `date_week` is the beginning day of the week (Monday). I want to convert `date_week` to day except by the first week of the year, where I want to isolate the day (in this case is 2012-01-01 which was Sunday). I have tried this, but something's wrong.

```
df['date_start'] = np.where((df['year']==2012) & (df['week']==1), \
                            pd.to_datetime(str(20120101), format='%Y%m%d'), \
                            pd.to_datetime(df['date_ix'], format='%Y%W%w'))

    year    month   week    sales   date_ix     date_week   date_start
0   2011    12      51      10000   2011501     2011-12-12  1323648000000000000
1   2011    12      52      12000   2011511     2011-12-19  1324252800000000000
2   2011    12      53      11000   2011521     2011-12-26  1324857600000000000
3   2012    1       1       5000    2012001     2011-12-26  2012-01-01 00:00:00
4   2012    1       2       12000   2012011     2012-01-02  1325462400000000000
5   2012    1       3       11000   2012021     2012-01-09  1326067200000000000
```

The expected result should be:

```
    year    month   week    sales   date_ix date_week   date_start
0   2011    12      51      10000   2011501 2011-12-12  2011-12-12
1   2011    12      52      12000   2011511 2011-12-19  2011-12-19
2   2011    12      53      11000   2011521 2011-12-26  2011-12-26
3   2012    1       1       5000    2012001 2011-12-26  2012-01-01
4   2012    1       2       12000   2012011 2012-01-02  2012-01-02
5   2012    1       3       11000   2012021 2012-01-09  2012-01-09
```

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try, ``(df['year']==2012) & (df['week']==1)`` filter instead

Comment: I will update my question because of the wrong result I get. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose `df['year']==2012` and `df['week']==1` with parentheses because of the priority of `==` and `&`.

```py
df['date_start'] = np.where((df['year']==2012) & (df['week']==1), \
                            pd.to_datetime(str(20120101), format='%Y%m%d'), \
                            pd.to_datetime(df['date_ix'], format='%Y%W%w'))
```

Then change `pd.to_datetime(str(20120101), format='%Y%m%d')` in `np.where` to `pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y')`

```py
df['date_start'] = np.where((df['year']==2012) & (df['week']==1), \
                            pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y'),
                            df['date_week'])
```

```
print(df)

   year  month  week  sales  date_ix  date_week date_start
0  2011     12    51  10000  2011501 2011-12-12 2011-12-12
1  2011     12    52  12000  2011511 2011-12-19 2011-12-19
2  2011     12    53  11000  2011521 2011-12-26 2011-12-26
3  2012      1     1   5000  2012001 2011-12-26 2012-01-01
4  2012      1     2  12000  2012011 2012-01-02 2012-01-02
5  2012      1     3  11000  2012021 2012-01-09 2012-01-09
```

Comment: Hello @Ynjxsjmh, thank you but the `date_start` of the week 1 of year 2012 should be 2012-01-01 as mentioned in my question. Please, do you know where I am doing a mistake? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer @Ynjxsjmh, I didn't know that trick of converting a year to a full date. Hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
df['date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.week.astype(str)+
                       df.year.astype(str).add('-1') ,format='%V%G-%u')
```

This will give `date_start` as the date of the Monday of the week of interest.
(Note that there is a shift with your current date_start, you might want to add a 1 week tmimedelta to compensate for it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but just for week 1 of 2012 it should be 2021-01-01, not 2011-12-26.

Comment: With this code I get 2021-01-02 for week 1 of 2012, which is the date of the first Monday of that year